# Add leading 0's to text field in Access Database

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a text field which needs to have at least 8 characters in the string regardless of the data the user inputs. I want to be able to add leading 0's to the data the user inputs to reach 8 characters if needed.

I have read multiple times to user Format(fieldname, "00000000") but I clearly don't know Access well enough because that just forces users to enter 8 digits which is not what I want.

Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this is neither a free consulting/design/coding nor debugging service, tutorial site nor web search replacement. We however can can help solve [certain problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (for free), but it's **your** job to **[put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** on the subject in the first place, including elementary **[(re)search](https://google.com/)**. In the end it's your problem not ours, isn't it?

Comment: Man I've been searching for a while now, no result is coming up that seems to be working or makes any sense as to how to implement. I was just looking for a more direct conversation. Maybe I worded it poorly but I simply do not understand how to do what I am asking nor if it is even possible because nothing I have found is clear.

So what research and effort are you looking from me? I've tried validation rules, formats, none are doing what I want.

Comment: @IAmDaedem simply follow Link given by Marcin

Comment: FWIW - If the user entered a number (say `12345`) then `Format(12345,"00000000")` will create the string `"00012345"`.  However, if the users are not entering a number, but a string (say "ABC12"), then you will want to use `Right("00000000" & fieldname, 8)` which will generate the string "000ABC12" (or, if the user entered the string `"12345"` it will generate the string `"00012345"`).  Without seeing your current code, it's hard to tell what you need.

Comment: Why allow user to enter more than 8 characters? This is a text type field? Set the field size in table design. You don't need the data saved with the leading characters, just display with the leading characters in reporting. Are both alpha and numeric allowed? Are they intermixed?

Comment: @YowE3K yes it's a string and I'll see if that works, that sounds like what I want.